# How can i get started using Etag URL fingerprinting for my Opencart website?

Tags: .htaccess, url, caching, opencart, fingerprinting

Im pretty new to scripting and coding. I have now picked an interest in speeding up my website. To do this i would like to begin leveraging browser caching.

I've read up on a couple of things but i'm now struggeling to make the right decision.

As far as i understand there are three options:

-expires
-max age
-Etag (while using max age)

The first two are not suitable for an e-commerce website (opencart btw) in my opinion. But are far easier to implement than the Etag as i understand.

I got as far as getting the expire and max age working in my testing eviroment but then i get problems with outdated client side rendering of my webpage.

So in conclusion i wanna go for the Etag but i have no clue where to start! Is there anyone (maybe with opencart experience aswell?) who can help me get on the way?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

George

Answer (score 1):

ETags are not that complicated to implement. Here's a snippet of code for your .htaccess file that will enable ETags for your images and other files that don't change that often:

```
# ETags Settings (for Cache purposes)
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch \.(?i:jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|xml)$>
  FileETag MTime Size
 </FilesMatch> 

 <FilesMatch \.(?i:php)$>
  Header unset ETag
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
  Header set Pragma "no-cache"
  FileETag None
 </FilesMatch> 
</ifModule>

# Expires Settings
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On 
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

 # Images
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Just a little background (though I'm sure you already know) and explanation:

ETags are more reliable than expires due to the fact that browsers that honor the expire directive will not change the image/file for the lifetime it is given, regardless if there are any changes. However ETags can be configured to indicate a browser when to change the image.

In the code provided above **FileETag MTime Size** will have browser updating the images, css, js and xml files (the ?i: is to do a case-insensitive match) if there are any changes in size or modification time. And the best part: it supersedes expires directives!

Also, the code above will disable ETags for php files due to the dynamic nature of the content.

I included the expires directives for images because, at the time of me writing this, many speed checkers and validators will rank you a little bit down for not having them, even if ETags are set.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your clear answer! At the moment my manager is totally swamping me with work so won't be able to test this properly now but when i find the time, i'll let you know my results.